# Gunicorn 'Application Object Must Be Callable' error

Tags: python, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy an app written in Dash, using gunicorn and nginx. I successfully deployed this same app a few months ago, when I knew what I was doing. I wanted to make some updates and redeploy, but now the deployment wont work, even if I get rid of all my updates. When I run gunicorn, I get an error, `Application must be callable`.

I have my project in `folder`, which contains `unified.py` file, which has my app. In `unified.py`, `app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)` so I'm defining my app variable as app.

I run `gunicorn folder.unified:app` and get this error.
However, if I run `from folder.unified import app` I get the app object and all the proper attributes, no problem.

I have tried all sorts of variations on the gunicorn call (such as being in the project folder and saying `gunicorn`unified:app`, being the parent folder and using`gunicorn folder:app`,`gunicorn folder:unified`. I know that it can work because it was working before. But for the life of me, I cannot figure out what is going on right now.

I expect it to run similarly to when I run the app with python using `python unified.py`.

There was a moment where I thought I solved it because I started getting a different error (saying I couldn't get a .pkl file from another folder), but then I commented out those lines in my `unified.py` file and it went back to the same `Application must be callable` error!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`gunicorn unified:app.server`

Cross reference from the Plotly forums where I found the solution:
https://community.plot.ly/t/error-with-gunicorn/8247

Comment: This answer has since changed based on an update to gunicorn. On newer versions of gunicorn the correct syntax would be `gunicorn unified:server`. This is based on the same link.

Answer (score 14):

add server after defining app in main code. (Ex:main.py)

```
app=dash.Dash(__name__)   
server=app.server
```

then run gunicorn in terminal

```
gunicorn main:server
```

if you want to access over LAN and set a port and workers

```
gunicorn -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:4000 app_test:server
```